# CoreData利用時のNSManagedObject内メソッド呼び出し時に起こるEXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, json, swift3, database, coredata

JSONとCoreDataの連携について下記サイトのサンプルコード(Swift-3)を元にプログラムを書いています.
http://docs.fabo.io/swift/coredata/001_json.html

```
let wordDatas: Words = Words(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
do {
     try wordDatas.updateFromDictionary(dataDictionary: jsonData as! [String : Any])
   } catch {
            print("Error updateFromDictionary:\(error)")
   }
```

内容はJSONファイルを読み込みCoreDataへ保存するコードです.
問題の箇所は上記の部分で,(サンプルより変数名等が違うだけのものですが)3行目のメソッド呼び出しの行でEXC_BAD_ACCESSが出て異常終了してしまいます.
Wordsクラスの中身も(これも変数名が違うだけですが)下記に示しておきます.

```
@objc(Words)
public class Words: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var english: String
    @NSManaged var japanese: String
    func updateFromDictionary(dataDictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        // バリデーション.
        guard let tmp_id: NSNumber  = dataDictionary["id"] as? NSNumber,
            let tmp_english: String   = dataDictionary["english"] as? String,
            let tmp_japanese: String = dataDictionary["japanese"] as? String

            else{
                throw NSError(domain: "Failed validation of JSON object. ", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }

        // データを反映.
        id = tmp_id
        english = tmp_english
        japanese = tmp_japanese
    }

}
```

jsonDataの中身はprintで確認した所,うまくJSONファイル内の1行目のテーブルを読み込めているようでした.
EXC_BAD_ACCESSのよくある原因としては解放済みのオブジェクトへアクセスした場合などのようですが,インスタンスを生成した直後にも関わらずこのような現象が起きてしまい悩んでおります.

Comment: モデルファイルに設定したクラス名が正しくシステム側に認識されていない可能性が高そうです。`let wordDatas: Words = ...`の次の行に`print(type(of: wordDatas))`と言うのを入れると何が出力されるでしょうか。(どうでも良いですが、`datas`なんて「変英語」はできればコードには使わない方が良いかと…)モデルファイルの設定がまずかったりモデルファイル作成後にソースコードをあちこち修正すると発生することがあります。`id`, `english`, `japanese`などの`@NSManaged`プロパティには動的にアクセスされるのでデータさえ取れていればアクセスできるのですが、クラスに定義したメソッドには正しくそのクラスのインスタンスが作られていないとアクセスできない、と言うことになります。上記の確認を行うとともに、モデルファイルを再編集して該当エンティティのクラスを一旦削除してつけなおす、等してみてください。

Comment: print(type(of: wordDatas))で確認した所Wordsと出ました. しかしもうお手上げ状態だったのでプロジェクトを作り直してモデルファイル周りの設定を慎重に行ったところうまく動きました(T_T) イマイチ解せませんが Le Pere d'OOさんが仰ったとおりやはりあちこちこねくり回したおかげで整合性が取れなくなっていたのでしょうか。。。本当に助かりました。どうもありがとうございます。あとDataってすでに複数形だったんですね勉強になりました笑

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。手間のかかるプロジェクトの作り直しをされたということであまりお役に立てなかったようですが、解決できたということでとりあえずほっとしております。また何かお気付きの点がありましたら情報共有していただけると助かります。